# how to save object variable in application class when it was destroyed by system when app was put on background several hours

Tags: java, android

after i put app on background several hours and reuse it ,i always got a nullpointer exception,it was caused like this:
when users login my app ,i put BeanUser object in application class,and use it in activities
but it was destroyed by system .so ,how to save it when application before destroyed?
sharedpreferences does't work,it can only save like int,boolen etc..
thanks for all helps,and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to flatten your object and write it to disk somehow, either via the [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) interface, or storing the members of the object in an XML file or something manually and reading it back.

You could also save the data from the object into an SQLite database and read it back when your app starts again

Answer (score 0):

Use [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) to save and restore state while Android puts your Activity to sleep